# Trying to bind inputs Inheriting by other input

Tags: php, json, ajax, adminlte

I'm trying to bind other inputs by one input, previously i made an example that i saw on internet to understand and practice, the example i made it was fine and it fill all the data that i ask but when i try to implement into My project this does not do nothing, in the console, doen't show me an error or something that can tell me what is happen
i'm using PHP 7 and the templates of Admin LTE

this is my form

```
<form name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="hidden" name="idventa" id="idventa">
    <label>Numero de viaje:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="num_viaje" id="num_viaje" maxlength="256" placeholder="Número de viaje" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Cliente:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="256" placeholder="Cliente">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Destino:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="destino" id="destino" maxlength="256" placeholder="Destino">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Operador:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="operador" id="operador" maxlength="256" placeholder="Operador" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Número de operador:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idoperador" id="idoperador" maxlength="256" placeholder="Numero de operador" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Tipo de operación:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipoOperacion" id="tipoOperacion" maxlength="256" placeholder="Tipo de operación" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Viatico:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="viatico" id="viatico" maxlength="256" placeholder="Viatico" required onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Caseta:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="casetas" id="casetas" maxlength="256" placeholder="Casetas" required onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Extras:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="extras" id="extras" maxlength="256" placeholder="Extras" required onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Cantidad en Diesel:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="diesel" id="diesel" maxlength="256" placeholder="Diesel" required onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Desgaste 5%:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="desgaste" id="desgaste" maxlength="256" placeholder="Desgaste 5%" onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Utilidad:</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="utilidad" id="utilidad" maxlength="256" placeholder="Utilidad" onchange="sumar(this.value);">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Inversión total:</label>
    <span id="spTotal"></span>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" maxlength="256" placeholder="Total">
  </div>
  <div id="estado">Esperando input.</div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnGuardar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>

    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cancelarform()" type="button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Cancelar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

the footer i have apart and i put the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/relleno.js"></script>
```

relleno.php is these

```
$(function(){
   /* Ponemos evento blur a la escucha sobre id nombre en id cliente. */
   $('#cliente').on('blur','#nombre',function(){
      /* Obtenemos el valor del campo */
      var valor = this.value;
      /* Si la longitud del valor es mayor a 2 caracteres.. */
      if(valor.length>=3){

         /* Cambiamos el estado.. */
         $('#estado').html('Cargando datos de servidor...');

         /* Hacemos la consulta ajax */
         var consulta = $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'cliente.php',
            data:{nombre:valor},
            dataType:'JSON'
         });

         /* En caso de que se haya retornado bien.. */
         consulta.done(function(data){
            if(data.error!==undefined){
               $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: '+data.error);
               return false;
            } else {
               if(data.destino!==undefined){$('#nombre #destino').val(data.destino);}
               if(data.viatico!==undefined){$('#nombre #viatico').val(data.viatico);}
               if(data.casetas!==undefined){$('#nombre #casetas').val(data.casetas);}
               if(data.extras!==undefined){$('#nombre #extras').val(data.extras);}
               if(data.diesel!==undefined){$('#nombre #diesel').val(data.diesel);}
               if(data.desgaste!==undefined){$('#nombre #desgaste').val(data.desgaste);}
               if(data.utilidad!==undefined){$('#nombre #utilidad').val(data.utilidad);}
               if(data.total!==undefined){$('#nombre #total').val(data.total);}
               $('#estado').html('Datos cargados..');
               return true;
            }
         });

         /* Si la consulta ha fallado.. */
         consulta.fail(function(){
            $('#estado').html('Ha habido un error contactando el servidor.');
            return false;
         });

      } else {
         /* Mostrar error */
         $('#estado').html('El nombre tener una longitud mayor a 2 caracteres...');
         return false;
      }
   });
});
```

and in where i make the search into the data base is these cliente.php

```
<?php

/* Conectar a una base de datos de MySQL invocando al controlador */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbsistema;host=localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = '';

try {
    $gbd = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if(!empty($_POST['nombre'])){ 

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre = '$nombre'";  
$stmt = $gbd->prepare($sql);
$stmt ->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($arrDatos);
  if($arrDatos){
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row) {
      if ($nombre = $row['nombre']) {
        $return = array ('destino'=>$row['destino'],'viatico'=>$row['viatico'],'casetas'=>$row['casetas'],'extras'=>$row['extras'],'diesel'=>$row['diesel'], 'desgaste'=>$row['desgaste'],'utilidad'=>$row['utilidad'],'total'=>$row['total']);
      }      
    }
  } else {
    $return = array('error'=>'El nombre no esta guardado en la base de datos');
  }
  die(json_encode($return));
}
```

hope someone can helpme to find my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on my view in the $.ajax functtion. As data you give a json statement with variables you doesnt define (or i didnt saw it)

`data:{nombre:valor},`

On the other hand, you define dataType:json, but dataType json is not the type of data on submit, its the definition for the data, that returned back from this ajax call. And maybe, but im not sure atm, you should stringify the data (JSON.strinfiy(yourJSONObject)) because on data, you cant pass direct JSON Objects. Even when you after use $_POST to access it. Then the data has to be passed in form of &field=value&field=value&field=value....